# Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am trying to embed a JW Player 7 on my WordPress site. I have done this on another WP site with no issues and on my old site. I am not sure if this is an issue with the theme I am using or not. The page is http://www.stream.mesquiteweather.net/ I have the path to the js file in the head via a plugin as for some reason when I added it directly to the header.php file for the template it doesn't show up. With the plugin when I view source I can see it is added. I am getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined" twice in two different places and I am not sure how to resolve it as I am not good with javascript and my searches have come up empty. The actual player is in a separate PHP file which I am calling it into the template for simplicity. Ether way adding it directly to the template or using it in an include, it won't load. I think it has something to do with the template but, I don't use WP often so not familiar with what could be causing it.

I know it has something to do with it not calling the path before loading the script but, I am not sure how to get around that. That is my current thinking. I may be wrong.

Any suggestions?

-Thanks

Comment: Did you included the file? Is the file being added properly? What do you get when you run `jwplayer` on your console, after opening the site?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, Yes and "Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined". This was all outline in my original post as well and could have been easily verified by viewing the link I posted for further verification and troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you checked the network tab on your console for any 404 errors? Dod you tried anything else? Where's the code you used?

Comment: I've visited the link and the jwplayer file isn't being included **anywhere**. I checked the network tab and all you're loaded is disqus, google maps and google analytics. The file is not being included. Also, all questions require that the problematic code is added, so we can help on it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Did you happen to visit the link that I posted in my original post? All the answers to your questions can be easily answered from the link.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel there is no problematic code to post. It is a rendering issue which is why I included the link to the site for further troubleshooting as to what could be causing it. And yes, jwplayer.js is loading when you view it from the network tab and refresh the page. You can also do "view source" and see the code is included.

Comment: You have `<script type=”text/javascript” src="//mesquiteweather.net/stream/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
`. Have you tried to use proper quotes on the type? Or remove it entirely?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes and yes

Comment: Then I don't know. I'm sorry but I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has long been an issue with JW Player and MooTools not playing nice together.

With versions of JW Player earlier than JW 7.4 you could overcome this simply by loading the JW library before MooTools.

However, with JW7.4+, this solution no longer works.

Fortunately though MooTools have resolved the issue in the latest version of their library, so probably the best solution would be to update MooTools to v1.6 if possible.

Here's an example of your page with just the MooTools library updated: http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/debug/texan78/

PS: you may also be interested in the "Streamy" component offered as part of my Tatami for Online Video solution in order to elegantly manage your stream availability. Here's an updated page with a Tatami/Streamy embed: http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/debug/texan78/with-streamy.php

An example Tatami/Streamy snapshot can be seen here: http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/solutions/tatami/?share=dhoAJvxfYW

Comment: Thank you so much! During my research I did come across this Moo Tools conflict. Now or the stupid question unless I am just missing something. How do I update that as I do not have a MooTools plugin installed. I have noticed it bundled in with the Gantry 4 Framework which my theme needs to work. There is a Gantry 5 but, the theme isn't updated to use it. How can I update to MooTools V1.6. BTW, I love that video solution. I will be implementing that as soon as I get this functioning as I have been looking for something like that.

Comment: Got it figured out and sorted and it's working now! Thank you so much for your help and your direction. I am going into those other video solutions you suggested.